# What's the difference between git-tf and git-tfs?

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc, git-tfs, git-tf

I've recently been getting really fed up with TFS. I've heard that there is a light at the end of the tunnel though. Apparently I can use either git-tf or git-tfs and treat my code as if it was managed by git, but be able to push/pull to/from a central TFS server.

My main question is I'm not sure which one of these I should use. There is git-tf which is officially supported by Microsoft, and there is git-tfs which has been around a lot longer. What's the differences between these and which should I try out first?

Comment: I feel for you. The sooner you can dump TFS, the better. Then just go straight command line with MSysGit. Don't bother with anything else. Worked out well for me for the last 5 years.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk I work with a pretty open team and such, so it might happen one day, but for right now it's too expensive to just drop since we have a lot of other things in TFS than source code

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Disclaimer: I [started the `git-tf` project](http://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/team-foundation-server-and-xcode-projects-with-git-tf) and although the project is now in very capable hands without me as a frequent contributor, you should absolutely consider my opinions on this to be *strongly* biased.  (And, assuming you're on Windows, perhaps unexpected.)

There are two fundamental differences between the two tools:

- `git-tfs` was built for Windows users and written on top of the .NET TFS SDK.  The TFS SDK will *not* run under Mono, so this makes `git-tfs` unsuitable for cross-platform use.
- `git-tf` was built for cross-platform users and written on top of the Java TFS SDK.  Thus, it will run anywhere that's supported by the Java TFS SDK (Windows, Mac, Linux, AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, etc...)  `git-tf` was explicitly created to allow Xcode users to access TFS.

On Windows, of course, you can use either.  I'm not going to necessarily say one is better than the other.  But I will say:

1. *My* biggest complaint about `git-tfs` is that it won't work on Mac OS.  If there was a way to make `git-tfs` cross-platform, then `git-tf` almost certainly wouldn't exist.
2. `git-tfs` is *faster* in some cases than `git-tf`.  Performance was *not* our priority in the first few revisions, correctness was.
3. Because `git-tf` has a wide platform support matrix, this means that its functionality is necessarily constrained.  For example, there is *no* UI.  `git-tfs`, on the other hand, has a `checkintool` command that will open the normal TFS Checkin dialog.  This can be exceptionally helpful in visualizing your changes.  (If I recall, you can open up a proper visual diff from there, etc.)
4. `git-tf` works by populating the git repository directly, downloading TFS objects directly into the git object database.  `git-tfs` works by creating a TFS working folder mapping in a hidden folder, then populating the git repository from that.  There's a disk penalty here, so if you have superginormous repositories, you might feel this.
5. `git-tfs` can try to map your TFS branches to your git branches.  A lot of people will see this as a positive for `git-tfs`, though I don't:  git's branching model (at the repository level) and TFS's branching model (represented as folders in the repository) are so radically different as to cause problems in anything but the most simplistic workflows.  But your mileage may vary.
6. `git-tfs` is actively developed by a community.  `git-tf` has not had the community adoption.

I don't want to make it sound like I'm saying `git-tf` is bad.  It's not.  I think it's actually pretty good.  But it may not be your best choice.

---

Update: [`git-tf` has reached end-of-life](http://gittf.codeplex.com/).  It is no longer maintained or supported by Microsoft.  We recommend `git-tfs` if you want a bidirectional TFS <-> git solution.

Comment: So basically use git-tf on non-Windows and git-tfs on Windows?

Comment: Looks like I'll go with git-tfs. I will never install Java on my dev box under any circumstances.

Comment: Over a year later, how much of this is still true?

Comment: For larger repos, git-tfs doesn't run into the out of memory exceptions that git-tf does. Pretty much the only argument for git-tf is it is xplat.

Comment: Now that .Net runs everywhere, maybe its time to migrate yours? :)

Comment: @Mrchief Mono's been great at running .NET for years.  The problem isn't the .NET code, it's the native code that's required in the TFS SDKs.

Comment: git-tfs did not work for us, but Git-TF did. So far, Git-TF has been a blessing.

Answer (score 31):

Disclaimer: I am a developper on the git-tfs project

Edit: activity around git-tfs [is reduced](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs).

There is a support of TFS branching in git-tfs (fetching existing branches, creating branches, merge branches more easily than with TFS,... using `branch` command). It works most of the time but not with complex TFVC branches workflow...

See:

- [Managing branches with git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md)
- [git-tfs branch command documentation](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/branch.md)
- [Another answer on stackoverflow on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710811/717372)

git-tfs is also perhaps the only tool that permit you to migrate from TFS(VC) to TFS(Git), managing workitems if needed, or plain git repository.

And some other good features...

<s>(And it is more [active](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/graphs/contributors) and more [supported](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues))</s>

Answer (score 7):

To anyone finding this thread:

`Git-TF` has been officially discontinued after not having been updated after 2013 and now explicitly suggests `Git-TFS` as an alternative.

> ## Git-TF End-of-Life
>
> Git-TF has reached its end-of-life.  It will have no further updates and is no longer be supported by Microsoft.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services now provides a simple import tool to import a Team Foundation Version Control repository into a Git repository.  We recommend that you use this to convert TFVC repositories to Git.
>
> If you require more advanced conversion needs, or you want to bridge a TFVC repository and work with a local Git repository, **we recommend the git-tfs project**.
>
> Git-TF should not be used for new projects, but it will remain on the Codeplex archive for legacy users.

*(Section [added](https://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage/history) to the project's [codeplex page](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) in April 2017 by Edward Thomson, its initiator and author of the accepted answer)*

`Git-TFS` seems to be actively maintained:
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/commits/master