# changing to TFS in visual studio online account

Tags: visual-studio

I just created visual studio online account and selected the option of Git instead of TFS. But i want to change it to TFS after creating it.There must be some option of settings and configuration to modify that setting but could not found it. Can anyone please help me on that. Please note that i've not yet created any visual studio project.

Thanks,
Khurram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between Git and TFS source control in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679725/switch-between-git-and-tfs-source-control-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer before posting?