# Git, GitHub, TFS, Git-TFS and VisualStudio.com

Tags: git, github, tfs, git-tfs

I am starting a project on my stand-alone pc using visual studio 2015.  In the past, I have used TFS and Git in team projects.  My preference for this new personal project is to use Git on my local machine in conjunction with TFS; which is also installed on my pc.

My code will be proprietary, and I do not want it hosted on GitHub or VisualStudio.com regardless of how great their security features might be.  How should I go about setting up an environment like that?  Is Git-TFS the answer?

Comment: I really don't understand what is the point to start a new project, and wishing to have git in local and TFVC (if I understand well) on the server. Go full git in local and server! I am one of the main developer of git-tfs and this solution is not perfect and should be used only when you already have a project on TFVC and can't migrate. What you want to do is fire a bullet in your foot even before starting your project! Tfs now manage very well git projects (even better than TFVC ones...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want GitHub or TFS to host a remote repository which has a mapping relationship with your local repository.

You could use [Git-TF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) for combining the local repository of Git with the integrated ALM of TFS.

> Git-tf is a cross-platform bridge which allows developers to combine
>   the local repository capabilities of Git with the integrated
>   application lifecycle management tooling of Team Foundation Server.
>
> You can use a Git repository locally, and when you're ready to, check
>   in code to TFS. You can even continue to take advantage of integration
>   between work items (such as bugs and requirements) in TFS when you
>   want to enable end-to-end traceability of the relationship between
>   your work and your code changes. This bridge is a cross-platform tool
>   built with Java, so it runs on many operating systems, including OS X,
>   Linux, and Windows. This means that you can use Git clients (such as
>   Xcode) and maintain the ability to check code into Team Foundation
>   Server.

You can also use [Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) which is more suitable for windows user. Also take a look at this link:[What's the difference between git-tf and git-tfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866832/whats-the-difference-between-git-tf-and-git-tfs)