# Is is possible to directly upgrade the repository from TFS2015 to Azure devops git?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We have our source code in TFS 2015. We would like to move to Azure Dev ops and we havemove our repo.
We create a git repo in Azure Devops and I would like to use git TF tool to migrate all the history from TFS 2015 to git on my local machine and then push it to the GIT repo in Devops.
Can I do that or have to for sure upgrade my TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 first?
I am wonder if I can avoid that upgrade.

any advice would be much appreciated,

Comment: Agree with Philippe, Git-tfs should be a better choice, It could be easily used to migrate source history from TFSVC to a git repository.https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md

Answer (score 1):

> We have our source code in TFS 2015

I imagine that you want to say in TFVC in TFS 2015, right?

> I would like to use git TF tool to migrate all the history from TFS 2015 to git on my local machine and then push it to the GIT repo in Devops. Can I do that or have to for sure upgrade my TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 first?

Yes you can use git-tf with TFS 2015. No need to upgrade.

But be aware that git-tf won't migrate perfectly your history. For example, git-tf does not support branches.

Perhaps you will have more luck with [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) even if that will surely not perfect either...

Comment: Thank u so much. Also thanks for pointing out to GIT TFS i found that as well but was not sure which one works better. I can understand that history would not be perfect as GIT works differently than TFS so that should be acceptable if it gives us 80% of history

Comment: @user464291 This question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866832/whats-the-difference-between-git-tf-and-git-tfs