# Migrate tfs branches into git repo in Azure

Tags: git, azure, tfs, version-control, migration

Is it possible to convert my TFVC branches into git repo? Is there any article with pros and cons?
I use the latest Azure.

Comment: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to migrate multiple branches and a long history, your best option is git-tfs

There was also git-tf but it is no more maintained but surely still usable. See here for a comparison :

[What's the difference between git-tf and git-tfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866832/whats-the-difference-between-git-tf-and-git-tfs/13724059#13724059)

You also have the convert feature of Azure Devops but you can only convert 3 months of history and no branch support.

In the [git-tfs project repository](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), you have some simple examples, the documentation of all the commands and some links on some advanced use case.

So you have a lot more than what an answer on the subject could bring you (because I spent a lot of hours on that)