# Using git-tfs for local branching

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I've installed git-tfs, and done a `git-tfs clone http://.....`

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to do local branching using git-tfs?
For example, an equivalent of `git checkout -b myBranch`

The team I'm working on seem to use only one branch from what I can tell on the tfs server, so i'd like to branch locally if possible?

Comment: Do you want to use branching within your local git repository, or should the branches end up in TFS? If only you will use the branches, just use `git checkout -b` and merge into your master branch when you want to sync your changes with TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you do localy should be done with git (and not git-tfs) and you could do everything you want (create branch, rebase or merge,...).

git-tfs is only used to interact with TFS (fetch changesets or commit changesets).

But (because there is always a 'but' ;) ), you should NEVER modify the commits already commited to git-tfs! Just add commit to the 'master' branch and commit it on TFS...

If one day, you will use tfs branch, you could find answer in this stackoverflow question : [How do I use git-tfs and idiomatic git branching against a TFS repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129959/how-do-i-use-git-tfs-and-idiomatic-git-branching-against-a-tfs-repository/13710811#13710811)