# Limitations to consider when using git with TFS via git-tf or git-tfs?

Tags: tfs, git-tfs, git-tf

What will I actually miss if basing my source code handling on TFS (to get all the integration and reporting etc) but use git-tf or git-tfs locally?

Will I then be able to use the complete git functionally to branch and merge locally just as if used a git based central repository, or will there be a different workflow and limitations to consider?

We use feature and release development branches a lot and like to keep doing so, how does actually the TFS server handle this when pushing these locally using git-tf etc?

Comment: If you get it running please post it. The SVN-TFS bridge does only work for servers with domain controlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use git-tf (the MS version) firstly you will have to understand the commands you use will be different - they stuck an additional "tf" in every command. (eg `git tf push`)

The second is that branching will not work like git - I found (and this could be due to security setups and suchlike, even though I can create branches locally and on the server) that whilst you can branch your local git setup, you cannot push a new branch back to the server - you have to merge it onto an "offical" branch first.

If using TFS, I wouldn't bother trying to use any of the bridges (though svn-tfs bridge is very close due to the nature of TFS being close to SVN). I'd use the native client. I wouldn't choose TFS first though, but *if* that was what I had to use - the [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://holymonkey.com/team-foundation-version-control-client-in-linux.html) client would be my choice.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, git-tfs is more advanced than git-tf. I highly advice to use it instead of git-tf (for the moment).

With git-tf, you should clone each branch as a repository (and be unable to cherrypick, merge...) while in the last version of git-tfs you can do it and keep your workflow.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710811/3619

If you know git there is not problem to use git-tfs!

The documentation : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/

just know that if you use :

```
git tfs checkintool
```

or :

```
git tfs checkin
```

it will create a merge commit

and if you use :

```
git tfs rcheckin
```

it will commit each local commit in tfs and fetch and rebase automaticaly on these commits...

But read the wiki documentation, it's clear enough ;)

edit:
Contrary to what @gbjbaanb said, there is a lot of advantages of using git-tfs instead of plain TFS (if you know how to use git...). ALL what you could do with git locally works and is still an advantage (light branching, rebase, local commits, reworking commits, knowing exactly which version is checkouted, fetching and seeing changes WITHOUT merging them with your current workspace, better history,...).

Now with git-tfs, you could even create more easily than with TFS a TFS branch (you just have to create it before doing a commit in it, or rebase onto after creating it if you began your work in a git branch before... ).

The only thing that is not better than TFS, for the moment, is merging 2 TFS branches that is not supported. You should either do a merge with TFS if you want to see the merge in your history (what we generally want) or merge with git and checkin in tfs (and you won't see the merge changeset :( ).
A pull request[1] to resolve all this (and permit to manage merge commit a LOT easier than with TFS) already done and waiting for merge in the trunc (I have just to refactor Unit test and the feature be reviewed).

[1] https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/363